# Не работает метод while

Tags: java

Пишу программу которая должна при вводе цифры 1 из консоли дать возможность записать новое дело в список дел, ArrayList. Делаю это через цикл while. При запуске программы и вводе числа 1 выдает сообщение "Какое дело вы хотите добавить?" и все, если я ввожу строку пишет ошибку неправильный формат ввода (Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException), если пишу цифру 4 то выдает список ArrayList. Почему не работает код который находится в первом if(actionOfTheUser == 1)?

```
while((actionOfTheUser = sc.nextInt()) != -1)
        {
            //добавляем дело в список дел
            if(actionOfTheUser == 1)
            {
                System.out.println("Какое дело вы хотите добавить?");
                add = sc.nextLine();
                toDoList.add(add);
                continue;
            }

            //просматриваем весь список дел с порядковым номером
            if(actionOfTheUser == 4)
            {
                for(int numberingOfAffairs = 0; numberingOfAffairs < toDoList.size(); numberingOfAffairs++)
                {
                    System.out.println((numberingOfAffairs + 1) + " " + toDoList.get(numberingOfAffairs));
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: String add;//добавляет дело в список дел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что `nextInt()` читает число, без `\n`. Поэтому в условии у Вас `sc.nextLine()` и считывал этот символ перевода строки. И потом, когда `sc.nextLine()` считал `\n`, для `nextInt()` Вы пытались уже ввести строку, поэтому и была эта ошибка.

> [`nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt(int)) method will throw InputMismatchException if the next token cannot be translated into a valid int value as described below.

```
while((actionOfTheUser = sc.nextInt()) != -1)
{
    // Добавляем дело в список дел
    if(actionOfTheUser == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("Какое дело вы хотите добавить?");
        sc.nextLine();          // added
        add = sc.nextLine();
        toDoList.add(add);
        continue;
    }

    // Просматриваем весь список дел с порядковым номером
    if(actionOfTheUser == 4)
    {
        for(int numberingOfAffairs = 0; numberingOfAffairs < toDoList.size(); numberingOfAffairs++)
        {
            System.out.println((numberingOfAffairs + 1) + " " + toDoList.get(numberingOfAffairs));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, добавил sc.nextLine(); программа принимает данные с консоли. Но теперь она почему то не выводит эти строки в списке ArrayList. Показывает пустую строку. Но отсчет строк есть. То есть было 4 строки с текстом, добавили одну строку с текстом, при проверки показывает 4 строки с текстом и одну пустую строку.

Comment: @FDmitriyA, потому, что первый sc.nextLine() считывает перевод строки, который идет после ввода числа, а уже второй читает саму строку. Сейчас поправлю ответ.

Comment: Все работает! Огромное спасибо!!!!